# Android: Share image and text via intent.action_send

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, send

I am developing an app and need to add the "Share on facebook" button... I don't mind the user has to select facebook on an emerging dialog, but until now I have not been able to share image and text at the same time...

This is my code so far:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Wonderful search engine http://www.google.fr/");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Thats for sharing text... it shares only the link on facebook, not the text before... don't know why... Any code for doing this ok and with an image?

Thanks! José

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here. You want to send text and an image to the facebook app?

Comment: I want to share text and image on facebook... from my android app

Comment: To the face book App or site?  Does the App support that,?

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

apparently it is not possible...